# ¿Ciclo para hacer pino de navidad?, PHP

Tags: php

Necesito hacer un pinito de navidad de 3 niveles con un ciclo, a partir de un input donde se pide ingresar un número del 1 al 3.
**(Sin los espacios)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora he podido imprimirlo pero de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código actual:

```
<?php
    echo "<center>";

        for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){

        for ($k=1; $k<=3; $k++)

        {
            for ($j=1; $j<=$k; $j++)
            {

                    echo "*";
            }
                echo "<br>";

            }

        }
        echo "***<br>";
        echo "***";
        echo "<center/>";

?>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: Listo, gracias por la información.

Comment: Y cual es el problema con tu código?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con mi error, gracias

Comment: No entiendo cual seria el pino esperado, el primero que colocaste en la pregunta es el pino esperado?

Comment: Así es, el primero es el que quiero lograr

Comment: Me encanta este ejercicio navideño :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bueno puedes ahorrarte un `for` utilizando `str_repeat` y bueno te dejo el código:

```
echo "<center>";
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    for ($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
        echo str_repeat('*', $k + $i + 1); // La sumatoria se realiza para que la siguiente iteracion del arbol empiece en **
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
echo "<center/>";
```

Lo que hice es simple primeramente modifique tus `for` para inicializarlos en 0 (algo que talvez no era necesario) pero me ayuda poder hacer el calculo siguiente: como ves realizo una sumatoria con `i + k + 1` pues esto ayuda a controlar que en la primera iteracion empiece de 1 (*) un asterisco y luego en la segunda empiece con (**) dos y asi correlativamente, ésto se lo pone como parámetro en el `str_repeat` que lo unico que hace es repetir la cadena de los (*) para que no tengas que hacer otro `for`.

Resultado:

[image: arbol]

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que quería hacer!

Answer (score 4):

Esta es una forma de realizarlo y donde puedes definir el número de renglones de tu pino de navidad.

Este ejemplo calcula los espacios, inserta los caracteres "*" y al final inserta un salto de linea `<br>` :

```
<?php

$rows = 9;
echo "<center>";

    $spaces = 2 * $rows - 2; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) { 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $spaces; $j++){ 
            echo " "; 
        }

        $spaces = $spaces - 1; 

        for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++ ) { 
            echo "*"; 
        } 
        echo "<br>"; 
    } 

echo "<center/>";

?>
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]